# Jena command line and --strict

Tags: jena

I've been going through the code in Jena to figure out what happens when passing the --strict command line.   It seems like that there is no difference except for logging of warnings.  In CmdLangParse.java the strict mode is set and SysRIOT.setStrictMode(true) is called and under the covers both StrictXSDLexicialForms and strictMode flags are set.

```
@Override
protected void exec() {
    boolean oldStrictValue = SysRIOT.isStrictMode() ;
    if ( modLangParse.strictMode() )
        SysRIOT.setStrictMode(true) ;
    try { exec$() ; }
    finally { SysRIOT.setStrictMode(oldStrictValue) ; } 
}
```

Then only in CheckerLiters validateByDatatypeand validateByDatatypeNumericuse the StrictXSDLexicalForms attribute and if it finds a space, \n or \r it just logs it.  Below is the snippet from validateByDatatypeNumeric

```
    // Do a white space check as well for numerics.
    if ( lexicalForm.contains(" ") ) {
        handler.warning("Whitespace in numeric XSD literal: '" + lexicalForm + "'", line, col) ;
        return false ;
    }
    if ( lexicalForm.contains("\n") ) {
        handler.warning("Newline in numeric XSD literal: '" + lexicalForm + "'", line, col) ;
        return false ;
    }
    if ( lexicalForm.contains("\r") ) {
        handler.warning("Carriage return in numeric XSD literal: '" + lexicalForm + "'", line, col) ;
        return false ;
    }
```

Am I missing something or is there no difference between to two modes (strict and non strict)?

Answer (score 0):

`--strict` is a general flag for Jena command line tools.

For parsing, there is little difference as you note.  It switches off features and provides the minimum for the standard.  For parsing, there isn't much.